# E.F. NotSupportedException - Transition from LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-sql

i am making the transition from `LINQ2SQL` to EF and am having some trouble with some basic lambda expressions.

In the following example, I am trying to retrieve a basic list of client related data. This statement when run using a `LINQ2SQL` data context works fine.

```
var data = db.Clients.Select(c => c.Id + ":" + c.Firstname);
foreach (var item in data)
{

}
```

When i execute it against an EF data context i get:

```
 NotSupportedException - Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

`NB`: the Id field is an integer.

I have been able to fix the error by adding a `ToArray()` after db.Clients.

Can someone please explain if..

a) I need to make this kind of code change to every pre-exisitng statement in my solution to get it working with EF; and

b) Why does EF have so much trouble with a basic concatenation when `LINQ2SQL` was fine?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why it works in Linq2SQL and not in Entity Framework, but I can help you solve your issue.

I suggest you use the [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) function.

```
var data = db.Clients.Select(c => 
    SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id) + ":" + c.Firstname);
```

Personally, if I have to do any string manipulation, I try to place that only in my client code, like this:

```
var data = db.Clients.Select(c => { c.Id, c.Firstname });
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var stringData = String.Format("{0}:{1}", item.Id, item.Firstname);
    ...
}
```